# User "GET" request in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I'm trying to use the GET method to send and retrieve information from the server but I seem to be having some trouble with the formatting the data for transport.

Does backbone serialize the data into url parameters when using .save() .fetch() or .create()?

I'm trying to

```
model.save({count: 8},{type:'get'});
```

But apparently the object isn't being converted to url strings....is it I need to do my own serializing? or am I doing it wrong?

What is the convention when using ":get" instead of "post"?

Comment: model save will always post. use `model.fetch(data:{{count: 8}})`

Comment: you should read a bit more about RESTful interactions. A `save` should never be treated as a `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use get you need to pass processData:true in the options